# Use full screen modal on route change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to implement a full page modal that overlays immediately upon another page when a route is triggered. How can I accomplish this on AngularJS? I use Angular-UI's modal directive to open modals, but I am open to other options.

Answer (score 0):

The old AngularUI modal was very buggy and eventually got removed, however I don't see a particular reason why it shouldn't work for you if you're still using it now. It is up to you to modify the CSS however so that it appears to be full screen which could quite easily be done by setting both width and height to 100%.

In your controller, you can also put `$scope.showFullModal = true` and it would appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UI-Router and create specific routing based on the event to route to the state where you open the modal.